# If a user attempts to delete a record that was not found, should the server return a 200 or a 404?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, api, error-handling

My colleague have developed a convention in our API that looks like this:

```
...
  return Subscription.destroy({
    where: {
      id: req.params.id
    }
  }).then((count) => {
    if (count === 0) {
      Logger.log('warn', '- subscriptionController.delete : no record found')
      return res.status(404).json(['No record found.'])
    }
    Logger.log('info', '- subscriptionController.delete')
    return res.status(200).end()
...
```

The rationale was: if no records were found, then it was an invalid request because the user attempted to delete a record and that did not happen.

In my opinion, a 200 should be returned even if no record was deleted, as long as the ID provided to the controller is a valid ID.

What is the correct implementation?

Comment: Looking here,  http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html   404 would be the correct response.

Comment: JSON API spec suggests 404 http://jsonapi.org/format/#crud-deleting

Comment: if you don't return any content with your success response (which you don't), *A server MUST return a **204 No Content** status code if a deletion request is successful and no content is returned* according to the specs linked above :p - so, ironically, the 404 is the correct response, but the 200 is not :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually if the resource to be returned or modified can not be found, the API should return a 404. However, this can be mislead users to think the endpoint itself is invalid.

A 200 code implies that the requested action completed successfully, so a user receiving a 200 after a delete would assume that the record did exist and was deleted. A 404 implies that the endpoint can not be found.

If the api call is like `/api/record/1234`, then I would recommend returning a 404 because that uri does not exist.

If the api call is like `/api/record?id=1234`, then I would recommend returning a 403 or 500 error with a message saying the record does not exist. That way users know that `/api/record` is a valid endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You would get a 404. According to the HTTP standards. If you are searching for a record at an id that has no record; then the server will not be able to match the target at the specified URI.

[W3C http status codes](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html)